# Finding First day of week via php

Tags: php, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

Hi,

I want to find first and last date of current week and last week.
Similarly I want to find first and last date of current month and last month.

This has to be done in PHP. Please help.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php

Comment: *(reference)* [Relative Date Formats in PHP](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is quite powerful with [*relative time formats*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

```
strtotime('monday this week');
strtotime('sunday this week');
strtotime('monday last week');
strtotime('sunday last week');
```

*(this only works with PHP 5.3+)*

```
strtotime('first day of this month');
strtotime('last day of this month');
strtotime('first day of last month');
strtotime('last day of last month');
```

In order to get the first and last date of a month in PHP < 5.3, you can use a combination of [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (`date('t')` gives the number of days of the month):

```
mktime(0,0,0,null, 1); // gives first day of current month
mktime(0,0,0,null, date('t')); // gives last day of current month

$lastMonth = strtotime('last month');
mktime(0,0,0,date('n', $lastMonth), 1); // gives first day of last month
mktime(0,0,0,date('n', $lastMonth), date('t', $lastMonth); // gives last day of last month
```

If you just want to get a string for presentation, then you don't need `mktime`:

```
date('Y-m-1'); // first day current month
date('Y-m-t'); // last day current month
date('Y-m-1', strtotime('last month')); // first day last month
date('Y-m-t', strtotime('last month')); // last day last month
```

Comment: You provided excellent solution But unfortunately this works only on PHP5.3 not in 5.2. I have PHP 5.2.14. And this didn't worked!

Comment: @user365870: True, it is not documented anywhere, I just read it in the comment of the page.... anyway, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is also useful - first and last day of any week number:
date('Ymd', strtotime("2013-W01-1"));
date('Ymd', strtotime("2013-W01-7"));

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function for the first and last day of the week:

```
function week_start_date($wk_num, $yr, $first = 1, $format = 'F d, Y') 
{ 
    $wk_ts  = strtotime('+' . $wk_num . ' weeks', strtotime($yr . '0101')); 
    $mon_ts = strtotime('-' . date('w', $wk_ts) + $first . ' days', $wk_ts); 
    return date($format, $mon_ts); 
} 

$sStartDate = week_start_date($week_number, $year); 
$sEndDate   = date('F d, Y', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($sStartDate)));
```

It can probably be adapted to do month as well, but I wanted to get my answer in! :)

Comment: I actually found the forum post he references by Googling on my own, Thank you :) ...didn't even see his answer from that other stackoverflow thread...

Comment: Ok, then I withdraw my comment :)