# PHP "first date of this week" return last month

Tags: php, date

Running

```
var_dump(new \DateTime('first day of this week'));
```

Returns the 1st of September

https://3v4l.org/GIPKR

Is this a bug, and is there any workaround?

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

Comment: Some of the PHP date functions do not seem to work as expected. jddayofweek is another one that did not work for me.

Comment: I tried `last day of this week` as well. And it returned the last day of this month, which is Oct. 31. Weird.

Comment: It is perfectly normal : the doc indicate that 'first day of' return the first day of a month : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: FWIW, I would never rely on the automagic of parsing human sentences, unless I completely understood how this parsing works and how my input will be interpreted. This isn't too hard to do "manually".

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code :

```
var_dump(new \DateTime('monday this week'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this - [Finding First day of week via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439722/finding-first-day-of-week-via-php)  Also try this -

```
        <?php 
            // var_dump(new \DateTime('first day of this week'));


            echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week')), "<br/>\n";   

            echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week')), "<br/>\n";

        ?>
```