# How to find the first day of the week a given date belongs to?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

Given a timestamp I need to find the first day the week the timestamp belongs to.

e.g.

```
$format = "first day of week";

//convert to time
$time = strtotime("2011-07-01 00:00:00");

//format the time to the first day of the week
$date = strtotime($format,$time);

//Put the first day of the week into a pretty format
$weekStartDate = date("Y-m-d",$date);
```

The week start should equal 2011-06-27 at the moment its gone horribly wrong and equals 1970-01-01 which suggests to me the “first day of week” format is invalid.

Any ideas would be much appreciated thanks,

Comment: Have you var_dumped your strtotime outputs to see what you get?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, its a duplicate the answer is on the other question and is to use the format "last sunday"

Comment: $format = "first day of week"; should be "first day of this week", no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime("2011-07-01 00:00:00");

$weekStartDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last Monday", $time));
```

Answer (score -1):

Test it :

```
$time=[Your Request Time];

$dayofweek = date("w",strtotime($time));

if( $dayofweek != 0  )

    $firstdayOfWeek = strtotime( $time . " - " . $dayofweek . " days " );

else

    $firstdayOfWeek = strtotime($time);
```