# Getting first day of every week in 6 months

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to figure out how can I get the the first day of week for the last 6 months and can't get to a working solution.

If I write `date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("-1 week", date("Y-m-d"));` It just subtracts 7 days from the current date; what I want to do is to always return the date of Monday from that week.

Expected result:

```
2011-8-8 00:00:00
2011-8-1 00:00:00
2011-7-25 00:00:00
2011-7-18 00:00:00
etc
```

Comment: Im not going to really say much except http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php. Come on now. There are multiple examples with this type of thing right there.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php

Comment: Who downvoted? The question is well-formed and perfectly valid. (Though, @Georges, you should have shown us what you tried and what went wrong.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563796/repeat-week-days-events-like-google-calender friends any idea for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for ($i=0; $i<52/2; $i++)
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(1, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-date('w')-$i*7+1, date('Y'))) . " 00:00:00\n";
```

it's slightly changed from [Mike's Post](http://boonedocks.net/mike/archives/114-Figuring-the-Start-of-the-Week-with-PHP.html), who wants the sunday instead of the monday.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Pre-PHP 5.3, you can use `strtotime` instead:

```
<?php
define('NUM_WEEKS', 10);

$dates = Array();
$dates[] = strtotime('Monday');

for ($i = 0; $i < NUM_WEEKS-1; $i++)
    $dates[] = strtotime('-1 week', $dates[$i]);

foreach ($dates as $date)
    echo strftime('%c', $date) . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Mon Aug 22 00:00:00 2011
Mon Aug 15 00:00:00 2011
Mon Aug  8 00:00:00 2011
Mon Aug  1 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jul 25 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jul 18 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jul 11 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jul  4 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jun 27 00:00:00 2011
Mon Jun 20 00:00:00 2011
```

### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/Uf2GWSsV)

Answer (score 2):

> If you're trying to make Saturday (or any other day for that matter)
>   the first day of the week to select datasets,  here's a good
>   workaround:

```
<?php  $last_sat=date("z", strtotime("last Saturday")); 
$second_last_sat=date("z", strtotime("last Saturday-1 week"));  ?>
```

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

What you'd probably want is

```
<?php  $last_mon=date("z", strtotime("last Monday ")); 
$second_last_mon=date("z", strtotime("last Monday-1 week"));  ?>
```

etc..