# When a date is given how to get the date of Monday of that week in php

Tags: php, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

When a date is given I should get the date of Monday of that week.

When 2012-08-08 is given it should return 2012-08-06.

Comment: Try `date('w')` to get what day-of-the-week a given date is - monday is day 1. After that it's just math.

Comment: Agreed on the duplicate, but I like my way better :p

Answer (score 11):

```
function last_monday($date) {
    if (!is_numeric($date))
        $date = strtotime($date);
    if (date('w', $date) == 1)
        return $date;
    else
        return strtotime(
            'last monday',
             $date
        );
}

echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/14/2012')); // 8/13/2012 (tuesday gives us the previous monday)
echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/13/2012')); // 8/13/2012 (monday throws back that day)
echo date('m/d/y', last_monday('8/12/2012')); // 8/06/2012 (sunday goes to previous week)
```

try it: http://codepad.org/rDAI4Scr

... or a variation that has sunday return the following day (monday) rather than the previous week, simply add a line:

```
 elseif (date('w', $date) == 0)
    return strtotime(
        'next monday',
         $date
    );
```

try it: http://codepad.org/S2NhrU2Z

You can pass it a timestamp or a string, you'll get back a timestamp

**Documentation**

- `strtotime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

You can make a timestamp easily with the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function - it accepts both a phrase like "last monday" as well as a secondary parameter which is a timestamp that you can make easily from the date you have using [`mktime`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) (note that the inputs for a particular date are `Hour,Minute,Second,Month,Day,Year`).

```
<?php
    $monday=strtotime("monday this week", mktime(0,0,0, 8, 8, 2012));
    echo date("Y-m-d",$monday);
    // Output: 2012-08-06
?>
```

*Edit* changed "last monday" in `strtotime` to "monday this week" and it now works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work if the input date is 2012-08-06.

Comment: @irrelephant It does now :) +1 btw for the eagle eyes :)

Comment: Output is "2012-08-13" http://codepad.org/mCOrBDL3

Comment: @Chris interesting, working fine on my laptop here (PHP5.3.0)

Comment: @Fluffeh even weirder.... I tested it on my own server and the return is "2012-08-06". Hard to blame on timezone... I could see if the date in question were a sunday, but a wednesday shifting ahead a week? You're right... weird.

Comment: Aye, you will :) Though I am still pretty curious why that failed. Is `mktime` inherently unreliable across hosts?

Comment: @Chris Not sure, I will test it on linux when I get back home. Never had that much use for it myself to be honest.

Comment: For reference, my test was on FreeBSD, PHP 5.4.5, Eastern Standard Time. Codepad.org is PHP 5.2.5 on a Linux build, UTC.