# php first monday after certain date as string

Tags: php, date

I have a date given as a string. And I would like to get the first monday after this given date, again as a string.

```
$myDate = "2014-08-24"; // date given in Y-m-d
$nextMonday = ??? // how to get the next monday after $myDate?
```

This sounds like a question that was solved before, like [PHP get next occurrence of Monday from a certain date (with time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055935/php-get-next-occurrence-of-monday-from-a-certain-date-with-time) or [When a date is given how to get the date of Monday of that week in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771062/when-a-date-is-given-how-to-get-the-date-of-monday-of-that-week-in-php).
But it actually is a different problem, because I am running into a lot of conversion issues and a little bit confused how to solve this.

Comment: Could you show us your code, and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: _“But it actually is a different problem, because I am running into a lot of conversion issues”_ – you neglected to describe what those issues actually are.

Comment: not true, your first link solve it correctly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use this

```
<?php
$myDate = "2014-08-27";
$next_monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next monday", strtotime($myDate)));
echo $next_monday;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
2014-09-01
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/180726)**

Answer (score 12):

You can do it using the [**DateTime**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [**DateTime::modify**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-08-24');
$date->modify('next monday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Thank you so much!