# How to calculate date in PHP using variables

Tags: php

Can anyone help create this logic? Kind of difficult to explain...

Looking to take a date, add 3 days then select the next date based on a database value.

Say we start with:

```
$end_date = "2017-08-23 23:59:59"
$payday = 5; //1=monday, 2=tuesday, 3=wednesday, 4=thursday, 5=friday
//And we want to calculate $paydate:
$temp_date = $end_date + 3 days;
$pay_date = the first $payday(day of week) after $temp_date
```

Any ideas how to write this in php? This one is stumping me. Thanks!

Comment: this should get you most of the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379449/php-first-monday-after-certain-date-as-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? It will get a date, add 3 days, and then loop through the next days until it finds a day in the `$days` array (which you can get from a database):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2017-08-23 23:59:59');
function nextPayday($date) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
    echo "Date + 3 days: ".$date->format('D Y-m-d') . "<br>";
    $payDate = $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $days = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    while (!in_array($payDate->format("N"), $days)) {
        $payDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $payDate->format("D Y-m-d");
}
echo "Date + 3 days: ".$date->format('D Y-m-d') . "<br>";
echo "Next payday: ".nextPayday($date);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/CZLs0)

Or, if you need to find a next **specific** day, use this function instead:

```
function nextPayday($date) {
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
    echo "Date + 3 days: ".$date->format('D Y-m-d') . "<br>";
    $payDate = $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $day = "5";
    while ($payDate->format("N") !== $day) {
        $payDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $payDate->format("D Y-m-d");
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. This is exactly what I need (the second section).

Answer (score 1):

To add three days you can do this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-08-23 23:59:59');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));
$date->modify("next friday");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

You could also use a lookup table, or array, that matches number to named days of the week and use something like `$date->modify("next $days[$payday]");`
where

```
$days = [ [1] => "monday",
           .... etc
```

Comment: Thank you. After adding 3 days I am trying to take that date and find the next calendar day that corresponds with the 'pay_day' setting.

Comment: For example, $pay_day=5; //1=mon... 5=fri

Comment: So I am trying to take the new date (after adding the 3 days) and finding the first Friday from that date or newer

Comment: assuming payday will be every week you could just use `$date->modify('next friday');` and you could use a lookup table to figure out which next day you need to use

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, take a look at [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which extends PHP's DateTime object.

It allows you to deal with dates in a very clean and intuitive way. Based on your example:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('next monday')->toDateString();
```

Adjust that to your exact case.

Answer (score 0):

Another version to achieve the objective:

```
function nextPayday($dateString, $paydayNum) {
    $paydays = [
            1=>'monday',
            2=>'tuesday',
            3=>'wednesday',
            4=>'thursday',
            5=>'friday'
    ];
    $temp_date_stamp = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateString.' +3 days'));
    $pay_date_stamp  = strtotime('first '.$paydays[$paydayNum].' '.$temp_date_stamp);

    return date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $pay_date_stamp);
}

$end_date = "2017-08-23 23:59:59";
$payday = 5;

echo nextPayday($end_date, $payday);
```

result:

```
01-09-2017 23:59:59
```