# Want the first day of the week (Monday)

Tags: php, gnuplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

I want to have the first day of the week if I give any date and it works for all dates except Mondays as it gives me the previous Monday, not this Monday.

My code:

```
$beginweek = strtotime('last Monday', $timestamp); //$timestamp = a given date
```

Comment: There are [several different implementations here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php) Basically, you just need to determine if today is Monday, and if it isn't, use the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a condition to see if the current day is monday, else use 'last Monday'

Comment: Am I able to find a Monday in timestamp or will I have to convert it to readable dates first?

Comment: @Kevin - if (date('N',$timestamp) == 1) // then it's monday