# Calculate date for Monday of current week

Tags: php, date, mktime

Goal: If current day of week is any day other than Monday, display the date of the Monday of the current week. If the current day of the week is Monday, simply display today's date.

** This is what I wrote and I think it works but is probably not the cleanest way to determine the date. Having said that, does anyone see any reason why the code would be wrong or not work? **

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$day = date("w");
if( $day == 1 ) {$day -= 0;}
if( $day == 2 ) {$day -= 1;}
if( $day == 3 ) {$day -= 2;}
if( $day == 4 ) {$day -= 3;}
if( $day == 5 ) {$day -= 4;}
if( $day == 6 ) {$day -= 5;}
if( $day == 0 ) {$day -= 6;}
$calc = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-$day,date("Y"));
echo date("m/d/Y",$calc)."<br>";
echo "start date of work week is: ".date("m/d/Y", $calc);
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17081175/212940

Answer (score 15, accepted):

wont this work?

```
echo date("d m Y",strtotime('monday this week'));
```

Comment: `'Monday this week'` also works in the `DateTime` constructor if you want something more modern than `strtotime()`

Comment: Close, doing it that way echoed the upcoming Monday instead of the Monday in the current week. I was however able to look at the `strtotime()` method and get the right date by using `$test=strtotime("previous monday",strtotime(date("m/d/Y")));
echo "<br>".date("m/d/Y",$test);`

Comment: @mithunsatheesh This provides wrong information in my case. If date is 1st jan 2015 then it provides 2 jan 2015 as monday of current month while week should count from monday. I there a way to count current week start  from monday rather than sunday?

Comment: @RNKushwaha - this works based on "a week starts on Sunday". you can read the threads on [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 0):

You Can try This :

`date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
                    $day = date("w")."<br>";
                    echo $day;
                    //if( $day == 1 ) {$day = 0;}
                    if( $day == 2 ) {$day -= 1;}
                    if( $day == 3 ) {$day -= 1;}
                    if( $day == 4 ) {$day -= 1;}
                    if( $day == 5 ) {$day -= 1;}
                    if( $day == 6 ) {$day -= 1;}
                    if( $day == 0 ) {$day -= 6;}
                    $calc = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-$day,date("Y"));
                            if($day == 1 ){
                                    echo date("m/d/Y")."<br>";
                                    echo "start date of work week is: ".date("m/d/Y");                                      
                            }   
                            else{
                                    echo date("m/d/Y",$calc)."<br>";
                                    echo "start date of work week is: ".date("m/d/Y", $calc);                                      

                            }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime('monday this week');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works if your week starts on Monday.

```
$monday = strtotime('this sunday', strtotime($startingDate)) - (86400 * 6);
```

While if you do it the way @mithunsatheesh suggested works perfectly if your week starts on Sunday.