# How do I programmatically getting the startDay of the current week using PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

[image]

Today is April 7th, and the closest the beginning date of the week is April `5`.

How do I programmatically getting the startDay of the  current week using PHP ?

---

I've tried

```
$dateStartWeek = date('N', strptime('%m-%d-%g', $dateString));
dd($dateStartWeek);
```

and tried

```
    function getFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime $date, $firstDay = 0) {
        $offset = 7 - $firstDay;
        $ret = clone $date;
        $ret->modify(-(($date->format('w') + $offset) % 7) . 'days');
        return $ret;
    }


    $dateStartWeek = getFirstDayOfWeek(date("y-m-d"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first day of week in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)

Comment: By "startDay", I assume you mean the nearest Sunday previous to the current date?

Comment: @esqew Yes, it's precisely that.

Comment: `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week'));`

Comment: @0stone0, Your return `"2020-04-12"` which is the upcoming sunday. :)

Comment: @cyber8200 Yea, you could use `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week'));`

Comment: It works, your answer is the most elegant answer. `$dateStartWeek = date("d", strtotime('sunday last week'));`

Comment: Clean, one line. I don't know why others write functions to do it when we should just call it.

Comment: @cyber8200 Yea, there are plenty 'hacky' solutions to this, `strtotime` with relative dates can be really useful ;)

Comment: The answers in to the link is NOT Helping me, it confused and very tedious. The answer on this post helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [relative date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) `sunday last week`

```
echo date("j F", strtotime('sunday last week'));
```

> 5 April

[SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e90e52d9a09ff8cbfd099122e212fdbee053ad2)

Answer (score 0):

Use relative `datetime` formats - https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

In your case:

```php
new \DateTImeImmutable('this week')
```

Comment: I got this `DateTimeImmutable @1586187250 {#437
  date: 2020-04-06 11:34:10.237062 America/New_York (-04:00)
}`, The answer is `5`, since Apirl 5 is the start date.

Comment: Ok, in case you start your weeks on Sunday, do `new \DateTImeImmutable('this week - 1 day')`